# How to wake up the sleeping thread in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, swift5

I have a Bluetooth framework delegate method where I get a response after a few milliseconds which I need to read from some other method running on a thread. Usually, the response is after 30-100ms from the write operation. As there can be multiple write operations in very short time I need to read the response as soon as possible.

```
//Delegate method-->
var readData?
func responseFromBLE(data: Data){
     readData = data
     //wake up the sleeping thread as soon as this method calls
}

//Here is the thread which writes to BLE and then it waits for 100ms before reading data
func writeSyc(data: Data?, key: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        BLEViewController.semaphore.wait() 
            writeToBLE(data: data!)
            usleep(100000).  //sleeping for 100ms
            saveTheBLEResponse(key, readData)
        BLEViewController.semaphore.signal() // releasing the resource
    }
}
```

I want to to speedup this operation and wakeup thread before 100ms as soon responseFromBLE(data: Data) method calls.
If that is not possible, let me know if there is any other trick I can use to speedup the write operation.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. You need to create appropriate data structures such as a queue or list that tracks your writes and can correlate the responding read/response data.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? The semaphore makes a queue of all my write operations. and it waits 100ms for the response. after that only it allows 2nd item in the queue to write.

Comment: No, you are waiting and hoping the response arrives and trying to correlate requests and responses. It will be more robust to have a proper queue structure,  any time you use a `sleep` you are almost certainly doing something wrong.